# CakePHP SimpleTest enum problem

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, simpletest, mysql5

CakePHP1.3 with SimpleTest can't treat enum type column.
How to resolve this problem.?

```
Notice: Schema generation error: invalid column type enum(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ENUM is not supported by CakePHP`, because it only works with MySQL. And CakePHP Community want SimpleTest to be a generic system which should support all major databases systems to achieve platform independence.

Try switching it to `varchar('10') or tinyint(1)` data types and control their values in model's `$validate`